# How to get hidden input value that was dynamically stored using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, servlets, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to implement `search method` for "chat channels" that for every query it represents the compatible results from `SQL table` from the database.Each result can be distinguished by a unique `ID` that is also comes from the `SQl` table.I don't want to show the `ID's` so I put them in a `hidden input` for each result using `ng-model`.Also, for each, result the user have a possibility to **subscribe** to the channel (subscribe button) displayed in this result,so in order to save the subscription properly,I need to get the `ID` saved in the `hidden input` of the same result.

Here's what I tried:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr class="separating_line" ng-repeat="x in result">
        <!-- ng-bind-html allows to bind a variable to the innerHTML part of the HTML element -->
        <td>
           <div class="col-md-8">
             <h4><b style="color: gray;">{{ x.Name }}</b></h4>
             <br><p> {{ x.Description }}</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
             <small><label style="color: gray;">Subscribers </label>{{ x.Subscribersnum }}</label></small><br> 
             <input id="hiddenId" hidden="hide" ng-model="idval=x.ChanID" />
             <button ng-click="subscribechannel()" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
           </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In the `controller` I send it in the following way to convenient `Servlet`:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/ExampleServletv3/subscribeservlet",{
        params: {
            subidval: $scope.idval
        }
})
```

But when debugging the value that I get in the `servlet` is `null`.

How can I solve this? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason to use hidden fields in an Angular application: you're never submitting forms. Always sending AJAX requests. Just store data in variables of your controller. And BTW, ng-model doesn't expect a statement which assigns a value to a variable. Read the docuentation about ng-model (although, I repeat, you don't need it here).

Comment: but I need specific result value ,how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any hidden field to do what you want. All you need is to pass a parameter to your function:

```
 <tr class="separating_line" ng-repeat="x in result">
     ...
     <button ng-click="subscribechannel(x)" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
```